# time data does not match format '%y-%m-%d'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

[image]

`self.train_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(train_date,'%y-%m-%d').date()`

when I run above code, I get below error

[image]

I don't get it..because I checked the date format.

Comment: Please replace images with formatted text in your post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Y` for match `YYYY` format, because `y` is for `YY` format of year:

```
self.train_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(train_date,'%Y-%m-%d').date()
```